# Using Perl, how do I loop through files with a specific filename template pattern?

Tags: regex, perl, loops, foreach

I have lots of images in a directory, some of them are named with an odd pattern of:

```
13May1999(20.16.10).JPG
```

So, I wish to loop through only those files that have two numbers, followed by three letters, follow by four numbers, followed by an open parenthesis mark, followed by two numbers followed by a dot, etc  according to the example pattern above.

Other examples of files with this pattern:

```
22Jun2000(15.23.14).JPG
03Mar1998(08.43.22).JPG
15Jul2005(14.25.15).JPG
```

~~~~~~~~~

So for some reason the following does not work, anyone see an error?

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl

# attempt to match files with pattern:  14jan1999(11.23.34).jpg

foreach  $f1 ( </\d{2}[a-z]{3}\d{4}\(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\)*/i> ) {
     print "file: |$f1| \n";
}
```

Comment: `/\d{2} [a-z]{3} \d{4} [(] \d{2}[.] \d{2}[.] \d{2} [)]/xi or next;`

Comment: that syntax seems to match for a string ... but is there a way to use this with a foreach statement ?

Comment: you can use it inside foreach to filter out bad file names

Comment: @RichWalt You can match for strings inside a foreach statement. Why would you think you can't, and how else would you expect to match your pattern, if not with a regex match?

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
opendir D, '.' or die "Could not open dir: $!\n";

foreach $f1 ( grep(/\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{4}\(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\).*/i, readdir D) )
{
  print "file is $f1\n";
}
```

Output:

```
file is 22Jun2000(15.23.14).JPG
```

Comment: I thought so as well ... but for some reason this is not working ... no error, but just not working  .... for the parenthesis, I have tried BACKSLASH( as well as a simple "dot" ... I have also checked and rechecked the pattern ... everything looks good, but it's not matching anything for my files:   21jan1999(12.12.12).JPG    any guesses?

Comment: If you use the `/i` modifier, you don't really need `[a-zA-Z]` in the main regex.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `glob` operator, but note that it uses shell-style globbing rather than Perl regexes:

```
for my $file (<[0-9][0-9][A-Z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]([0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]).*>)
{
    print "$file\n";
}
```

You would probably do better with a simpler `glob` expression that could match a few extra files and then use a full Perl regex to select exactly the names you need, especially if you want to dissect the file name.  For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $file (<[0-9]*(*).*>)  # Simpler glob - but a good filter
{
    next unless $file =~ m/^(\d\d[[:alpha:]]{3}\d{4})\(((?:\d\d\.){2}\d\d)\)\.(.*)/;
    print "$file ($1 - $2 - $3)\n";
}
```

Sample output on a directory containing many files, including those mentioned in your question (with one JPG extension replaced by PNG):

```
03Mar1998(08.43.22).PNG (03Mar1998 - 08.43.22 - PNG)
13May1999(20.16.10).JPG (13May1999 - 20.16.10 - JPG)
15Jul2005(14.25.15).JPG (15Jul2005 - 14.25.15 - JPG)
22Jun2000(15.23.14).JPG (22Jun2000 - 15.23.14 - JPG)
```

Comment: WORKS !!   Wonder why other example do not?

Comment: @mpapec: Uglier than that!  Boring too!  And hard to maintain.  I'd probably think hard about using a simpler pattern in the glob and then filtering the results with a Perl regex; maybe something like `[0-9]*(*).*` as the glob (the parentheses, in particular, will eliminate most mismatches), and then `m/^\d\d[[:alpha:]]{3}\d{4}\(?:(\d\d\.){2}\.\d\d\)\./` or something similar, with the option of picking out pieces of the name by appropriate captures, or whatever.